# Vibrate one time Taptic

Tags: ios, vibration

How to make iPhone soft vibrate **one** time?
Below code vibrates twice.
Is there any way to check how many times vibrate occur in simulator? :)

```
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccurred(.success) // .error .warning
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't test vibration on a simulator, Need to use a real device for checking vibrations.
2. for soft vibration, you can use UISelectionFeedbackGenerator and can also use UIImpactFeedbackGenerator with soft style like this:

// UISelectionFeedbackGenerator

```
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.selectionChanged()
```

// UIImpactFeedbackGenerator

```
let feedbackGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft)
 feedbackGenerator.impactOccurred()
```

Comment: Will your code  vibrate once?

Comment: Yes. try UIImpactFeedbackGenerator as explained above.